# How to rotate photos sent in whatsapp in iPhone 6s

Tags: iphone, ios, photos

Recently I switched to iPhone otherwise was an Android user.

I am trying to rotate the photo sent to my whatsapp messages left/right like within the app like there is a option in android. i can't find it in iPhone.

**Note: i am strictly not asking about the auto screen rotation.**

Answer (score 1):

To rotate a photo on an iPhone and share it with Whatsapp:

1. Go into the Photos app
2. Navigate to the photo you'd like to rotate & share
3. Once viewing the photo in full screen, if the toolbar and navigation bar are *not* showing, tap the center of the screen
4. Hit the `Edit` button on the top-right (note: if you're running the iOS 10 Beta, you'll need to hit the slider button on the bottom toolbar)
5. Hit the crop & rotate button (should be on the bottom left)
6. Press the rotate button (should be towards the bottom on the left) until the picture is rotated correctly
7. Hit the yellow `Done` button
8. Press the [share/export button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Yn8V.png) (should be in the bottom-left again)
9. If you don't see `Whatsapp` in the list of apps you can share the photo to, scroll all the way to the end of the app list to the more button, hit the more button, and turn `Whatsapp` **on.**
10. Exit out of the More menu and hit Whatsapp, at which point you can **share your correctly rotated photo to Whatsapp**.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: @JohnRomos, my question clearly describes about the photos i received in my whatsapp app. not about the photos i have in my photo album and want to send them. while viewing received photos in whatsapp, can i rotate them within whatapp?

Comment: @AmitShah it's up to the sender to rotate them correctly (using the steps above if they have an iPhone or similar ones for other devices) but you can also rotate them upon receiving them by opening up the Photos app (where WhatsApp photos should autosave) and rotating them yourself.